# "Permanent Suspension"

Tags: semantics, oxymoron

The Twitter statement about disabling President Trump's account mentions a "permanent suspension":

> [...] we have permanently suspended the account due to the risk of further incitement of violence.

Isn't a "permanent suspension" a self-contradiction? I would say a [suspension](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suspension#Noun) can be for an indeterminate amount of time, but if it's definitely permanent, then it's just a ban, not a suspension. Am I just plainly wrong or is this some sort of euphemism?

Comment: Have you checked any dictionaries? In particular, Cambridge Dictionary?

Comment: It's a little counter-intuitive, but a ban may well involve something different to a permanent suspension, at least for Twitter (e.g. whether they delete tweets or account information: for Twitter it may mean doing what they do for a temporary suspension, but without end). Looking at a good dictionary, some senses of suspension are temporary but it can also be used to mean a permanent condition as in a closure of a bank https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suspension

Comment: "The wools on which the permanent suspension of duties is intended under H.R. 9322 are principally those used in the production of rugs and carpets. " - United States. Congress. House. Committee on Ways and Means · 1960 · ‎Rug and carpet industry.

Comment: This is being used as a euphemism. The situation clearly demonstrates why.

Comment: Politics ... politely phrased ... because the person is, as he frequently reminds others, the *President*.